# How to create an API template that can be updated?

Tags: c#, .net, git, templates, repository

I have a C# CRUD API that whoever wants to use it only needs to add model classes to it and it will do basic CRUD operations on that model. Sure, similar projects may already do this, but that's not the point of this question.

What I would like:

- Anyone can create a new API from this CRUD API. Makes me think to use a public git repo that can be forked, git template repo, or .NET template.
- Updatable, once a new API is created from the CRUD API, if updates are made to the CRUD API, the new API could pull those updates in.  This removes the git template repo and .NET template options.
- I would like to create APIs from it. Since git does not allow forking your own repos, the forking option is removed.

Nice to have:

- Be able to rename the API.

The only solution that fits all of these requirements, including the nice to have, would be to have some sort of NPM package that reaches out to a git repository, get the files, and either creates or updates the new API. So, if I made an update to the CRUD API, I would push the changes to the git repo, then copy the API into a version named folder. Then, I would update the NPM package and point to that version.  The user could then update the NPM package, which would replace all of the files except those in the Models folder.

If they made changes to other files, and their new API is source controlled, they could compare changes and fix as needed.

This seems like a very convoluted and error prone solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When a connection is made there is a model that is serialized on the client and then deserialized on the server.  The model has to be the same on client and server.  So how do you dynamically change the model on both client and server?

Comment: Are you asking how my API actually works? My question is basically around how to have an updatable API template.  I'm not asking any questions about my API specifically. I'm just using it as an example.

Comment: I was just asking a hypothetical question.  How do you dynamically update a model on both client and server?  You first have to understand that a model needs to be changed at both client and server.

Comment: If you're asking about how a new API created from the CRUD API would be updated, it would be similar to an NPM or Nuget package. The user would either subscribe to new version alerts, or more likely, check-in periodically and if they want to update, they can.  If the solution was via forking, they would just merge from the upstream. Honestly, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Forking is the best option for everyone, except myself.  But, I was able to find this workaround described here: https://mzrimsek.medium.com/fork-your-own-github-repository-19ad4582b50a

The solution to get this to work for myself is to create a new repo, then add a remote to the repo I want to fork from (in this case, my CRUD repo).

```
// clone your new repository
git clone <new repository>.git
// navigate to the repository root
cd <new repository>
// add a reference to your original repository
git remote add upstream <original repository>.git
// pull all code from the original repository
git pull upstream master
// push all code to the new repository
git push origin master
// pull new changes from forked repo
git pull upstream master
```